# How to resolve issue "Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a frame with origin" in parent.document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have **popup fancybox iframe** opens on clicking a button in my site, I have two urls to access the site

```
1. www.xyz.com
2. xyz.com
```

On clicking on a button a pop up will appear, In that page i am getting the parent page URL as follows

```
parent.document.title
```

which works fine in first URL`(www.xyz.com)`, But in second URL`(xyz.com)`, it throws a JavaScript error as follows

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "www.xyz.com" from accessing a frame with origin "xyz.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Basically, I want to retrieve the parent page title, How to do this using jquery/javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is make sure the iframe isn't loading from the other domain name. If you've written the HTML for the iframe, it would need to change from something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.xyz.com/iframe/page.html"></iframe>
```

To something like this:

```
<iframe src="/iframe/page.html"></iframe>
```

Doing it that way makes sure the URL requested will always be from the current domain name, and it should work as intended. It's the same idea if you're using a plugin that grabs the URL from a link. Take off the domain so it loads from the current one.